# Named pipe in windows, difference between FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and PIPE_NOWAIT

Tags: winapi, ipc, named-pipes, overlap

I am using named pipe in windows and confused about the difference between `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and `PIPE_NOWAIT` which are parameters set in `CreateNamedPipe` ,I set parameters like this.

```
HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX |      // read/write access 
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,     // overlapped mode 
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message-type pipe 
    PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message read mode 
    PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // unlimited instances 
    BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR),    // output buffer size 
    BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR),    // input buffer size 
    PIPE_TIMEOUT,             // client time-out 
    NULL);                    // default security attributes
```

the `ConnectNamedPipe` return immediately and I get `ERROR_IO_PENDING` from `GetLastError`.With a nonblocking-wait handle, the connect operation returns zero immediately, and the GetLastError function returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.However the MSDN tells:
**With a nonblocking-wait handle, the connect operation returns zero immediately, and the GetLastError function returns *ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING*.**
so, what does `nonblocking-wait` mean, `PIPE_NOWAIT` or `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems the MSDN uses the term *"nonblocking mode"* when using `PIPE_ NOWAIT`, and the term *"overlapped mode"* when using `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. `PIPE_NOWAIT` is [*"supported for compatibility with Microsoft LAN Manager version 2.0 and should not be used to achieve asynchronous I/O"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea#pipe_nowait).

Comment: Very different options.  FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED sets up the socket so it can handle asynchronous I/O, you can call ReadFile() with an OVERLAPPED argument and handle the read completion later.  Very common for pipes, unless the traffic rate is very high you want to avoid blocking a thread too much.  PIPE_NOWAIT is useful for synchronous I/O, it prevents ReadFile() from blocking if there is no data yet.  Repeatedly calling ReadFile() is then required, polling in common terms.  Look at a library like boost::asio to take care of the plumbing.

Answer (score 4):

`PIPE_NOWAIT` mean that Nonblocking mode is enabled on handle. In this mode, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, and `ConnectNamedPipe` always **completed** immediately.

the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` mean asynchronous mode is enabled on handle. If this mode is enabled, **all not synchronous io** *[1]*   operations always **return** immediately.

so `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` vs `PIPE_NOWAIT` - this is **return** immediately vs **completed** immediately.

**completed** immediately (which include **return** immediately ) mean that io operation is already completed when api return. but visa versa not true. if operation **return** immediately this not mean that operation is **completed** already. if operation still not completed ntapi return code `STATUS_PENDING`. win32 api in such situations usual set last error to `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.

exist 3 way determinate when io operation completed in case asynchronous handle mode.

1. bind handle to *IOCP* (via `CreateIoCompletionPort` or
   `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo`). as result when
   io complete - pointer to `OVERLAPPED` which we pass to io call - 
   will be queued back to *IOCP* (in case `BindIoCompletionCallback` or
   `CreateThreadpoolIo` system yourself create *IOCP* and listen on it
   and call our registered callback, when pointer to `OVERLAPPED` will
   be queued to *IOCP*)
2. some win32 api such `ReadFileEx` or `WriteFileEx` and all ntapi let
   specify APC completion routine which will be called in context of
   thread, which begin io operation, when io operation is completed.
   thread must do alertable wait in this case. this wait is not
   compatible with bind handle to *IOCP* (we can not use APC routine in
   api call if file handle binded to *IOCP* - system return invalid
   parameter error)
3. we can create event and pass it to api call (via
   `OVERLAPPED::hEvent`) - in this case this event will be reset by
   system when io operation begin and set to signaled state when io
   operation is completed. unlike first 2 option in this case we have
   no additional context (in face pointer to `OVERLAPPED`) when io
   operation is completed. usually this is worst option.

*[1]* exist some io operations which is always synchronous api. for example `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, `SetFileInformationByHandle`. but almost io operations is not synchronous io. all this io operations take pointer to `OVERLAPPED` as parameter. so if no pointer to `OVERLAPPED` in api signature - this is synchronous api call. if exist - usually asynchronous (exception `CancelIoEx` for example where pointer to overlapped is related not to current operation but to previous io operation which we want cancel). in particular `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, `DeviceIoControl`, `ConnectNamedPipe`( internally this is call `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_PIPE_LISTEN`) ) is not synchronous io api