# Set stdin to non-blocking

Tags: windows, cygwin, stdin, nonblocking, luajit

How can I set stdin to non-blocking on Windows?

On Posix I can do this:

```lua
local ffi, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK = require 'ffi', 4, 2048
ffi.cdef 'int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, long arg);'
ffi.C.fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)
```

Afterwards, calls to `io.read` return immediately instead of waiting for input.

How can I do this on Windows? Support for Cygwin console is all I need. The snippet above runs without error, but has no effect.

Comment: If stdin is a pipe (probably for a Cygwin/MSYS2 terminal), we can set non-blocking mode via [`SetNamedPipeHandleState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-setnamedpipehandlestate). Note that it's not regular asynchronous I/O (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53239836/205580)), but we can't change an open file's mode from synchronous to asynchronous as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun, any idea how I'd get a handle to the pipe that stdin is coming from? In Posix I just count on FD 0 being stdin. Don't need async, just want `io.read` to return immediately whether there's anything in buffer or not.

Comment: That depends on the source of the file descriptor. If it's Microsoft's C runtime, you can get the handle via `_get_osfhandle(fd)`. I don't know about Cygwin.

Comment: I've discovered that fcntl works on WSL console, which I wouldn't be opposed to using instead of Cygwin, but the usual ways of entering cbreak/raw mode don't appear to work there -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289226/leaving-canonical-mode-entering-raw-cbreak-mode-in-wsl